# In bitvec, how does storage size affect loading?

Tags: rust, bitvector

How does the storage size affect how `load`ing works?.

As an example, in the below snippet, a 22 bit vector is separated into two groups of 11 bits. Each of these groups has the same pattern, storing the decimal number 1027.

```rust
    let vec22 = bitvec![u8 /* usize */, Msb0; 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, /* next */ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]; // 1027, 1027
    let chunks = vec22.chunks(11);

    let numbers = chunks
        .into_iter()
        .map(|chunk| {
            let number: usize = chunk.load();
            println!("{} {}", chunk, number);
            number
        })
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

When the storage size is `usize`, the `load` method returns the expected 1027. When set to `u8`, I can't seem to find a relationship between the printed numbers and the bit patterns,

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1] 896  // expected 1027
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1] 112  // expected 1027
```

How does changing the storage size affect these numbers?

Comment: This is an endianness issue. The [documentation](https://docs.rs/bitvec/latest/bitvec/field/trait.BitField.html#operation-and-endianness-handling) explains it well, especially the [`load_le`](https://docs.rs/bitvec/latest/bitvec/field/trait.BitField.html#tymethod.load_le) and [`load_be`](https://docs.rs/bitvec/latest/bitvec/field/trait.BitField.html#tymethod.load_be) (you want this one for correct results) docs.

Comment: `896 = 0b011_10000000, 112 = 0b000011_10000`, happens when you put the second partial byte of each slice left of the first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some fundamental knowledge on endianess and `bitvec` that's necessary to be able to answer the question,

- All computers agree that earlier elements in an array have lower addresses (i.e., "come first"), but bytes within the elements may be arranged in any order

  - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Overview
- In `bitvec`, `T` is used to describe the underlying element type storing the bits (u8, i16, u32, usize, etc).
- When loading a bit pattern that spans over multiple `T` elements into a new variable, `bitvec` needs to be explicitly told how to interpret the significance of bits across `T`s. If earlier `T`s are more significant, use `load_be`. If earlier `T`s are less significant, use `load_le`.
- The `load` function applies either the `*be` or `*le` loader that matches the arch of the machine it's running on, thus not portable, and which may or may not match how the bit patters have been set up.

Finally, to answer OP question as to why switching between `u8` and `usize` was producing different results: because uisng `u8` caused the 11-bit chunk to be spread across 2 bytes, thus making `bitvec` choose how to interpret the relative significance of the bits across those bytes. It just so happens that `load`, which uses the endianness of the machine it's running on, didn't match the intended endianness with which `vec22` is defined.